# ASP.NET Web Api metadata exchange?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Does anyone knows if there is any way to expose the new ASP.NET WEB Api REST interface metadata as with WCF (/help)?

```
<standardEndpoints>
       <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" 
                          automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
       </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Answer (score 2):

Help page generation is not supported in the first drop of ASP.NET Web API (in ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta) but is planned to be supported in later versions.  The generation of the Test Client website is also planned to be supported.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I would like to know more.

Comment: Source = [http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Web%20API%20is%20now%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Web%20API%20is%20now%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API)

Scroll down to "Will ASP.NET Web API support a test client and help page generation?".

You should also check whether it's now been implemented in the RC version.

Comment: From beta to RC: "You now can easily build custom help and test pages for your web APIs by using the new IApiExplorer service to get a complete runtime description of your web APIs."  source = [http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253817](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253817)